# Posicionar toolbar siempre en la parte inferior / Android Studio

Tags: android, xml

Buen día, me encuentro trabajando con un toolbar el cual quiero posicionar siempre en la parte inferior forzosamente logro el resultado pero al ejecutarlo en difeentes pantallas o emuladores el diseño se distorciona y yo quiero que sin importar la resolucion o tamaño de pantalla del dispisitivo el toolbar siempre se posicione abajo y de manera correcta, el codigo del diseño es el siguiente:

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4CAF50">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/flecha2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/regresarflecha" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp">

            <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/carrito_compra"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_fileName="otrocarro.json"
                app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="assets"
                app:lottie_loop="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCantProductos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:background="@drawable/caja_texto_circular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/rojo"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,SmallSp" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

Y el resultado deberia ser el seguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al ejecutarlo en diferentes dispositivos o emuladores me manda resultados como los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este seria el código completo del diseño de la activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etBuscador"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/caja_texto_circular"
    android:drawableStart="?android:attr/actionModeWebSearchDrawable"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="true"
    android:hint="Buscar exámen"
    app:backgroundTint="#0097A7"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:ignore="NewApi" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/microfono"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="250dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:onClick="onClickImgBtnHablar"
    android:src="@drawable/microphone"
    app:backgroundTint="#0097A7" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btnScan"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="290dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:backgroundTint="#0097A7"
    android:src="@drawable/barcodesearch"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rvLista"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="610dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4CAF50">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/flecha2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/regresarflecha" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp">

            <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/carrito_compra"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_fileName="otrocarro.json"
                app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="assets"
                app:lottie_loop="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCantProductos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:background="@drawable/caja_texto_circular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/rojo"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,SmallSp" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Esto quizás te pueda ayudar: https://code.tutsplus.com/es/tutorials/how-to-code-a-bottom-navigation-bar-for-an-android-app--cms-30305

Comment: Yo usaría un relativeLayout en lugar del linearLayout para eso. Luego, es tan sencillo como añadirle el atributo layout_alignParentBottom a tu toolbar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veo que usas un LinearLayout como contenedor principal, en este caso agrega un LinearLayout como contenedor para tu Toolbar y define el atributo `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` para alinear el `Toolbar` siempre en la parte inferior de tu pantalla:

```
<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
```

Ejemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white">

...
...
...

<LinearLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">


<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#4CAF50">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/flecha2"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/regresarflecha" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="25dp">

            <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/carrito_compra"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:focusable="true"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_fileName="otrocarro.json"
                app:lottie_imageAssetsFolder="assets"
                app:lottie_loop="true" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvCantProductos"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right|top"
                android:background="@drawable/caja_texto_circular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingRight="5dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/rojo"
                tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded,SmallSp" />

        </FrameLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

---

Te sugiero revises acerca de [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) lo cual sería lo ideal actualmente para crear tu layout y mediante el atributo `app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"` puedes lograr que tu vista se coloque perfectamente en la parte inferior de tu layout.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_width="match_parent">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    ...
    ...
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hola muchas gracias me ha servido muy bien

Comment: Excelente Adiel, saludos.